# Reading records from a text file in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a text file that contains multiple records in the below format

After reading the file, How do I store all these records, so that I can access and manipulate them, such as updating the fields in the record.The field and the field content are separated by multiple spaces.And the new records are separated by blank line

````
birthday      27-03-1984
address       27 Drew Street, Elwood,
              VIC
Postcode      3184
phone         0067282

name          Carlos
birthday      27-03-1988
address       27 langhlam, Southbank,
              VIC
Postcode      3184
phone         00672165```
````

Comment: As Java objects in a collection?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like tab-separated data. Use a CSV parser to read these, such as [univocity](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries like mentioned, but for this simple case can be done easily using `java.util` only:

```
public class PersonsReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("inputFile.txt")));
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.stream(content.split("\n\n"))
                .map(PersonsReader::toPerson).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // use persons list here
    }

    private static Person toPerson(String personData) {
        Map<String, String> keyValue = Arrays.stream(personData.split("\n"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        line -> line.split("\\s+")[0],
                        line -> line.split("\\s+")[1]));
        return new Person(keyValue.get("name"),
                keyValue.get("birthday"),
                keyValue.get("address"),
                keyValue.get("Postcode"),
                keyValue.get("phone"));
    }
}
```

Note that some of the keys do not exist in `keyValue` so `Person` constructor gets `null` for some of the parameters. Also, in `Person` constructor you can convert parameter to `Integer` if needed (and check first if `null`).

Comment: This code doesn't handle the multi-lined value for `address`.

Comment: @RolandIllig Correct. Although according the input file in the question it seems we have one address per entity. I took very simple approach for simple requirement. The OP can use this and improve/change it for her/his needs.